# Не отображается изображение ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, glide, sd

При запуске кода, не отображается изображение (просто белый экран). Все логкаты пишут что файл существует, и разрешения все есть, в чём секрет? Пробовал и через стандартные методы и сейчас пробую через Glide, но результата нету.

P.S. Изображение находится на SD карте

```
package com.example.mvpphoto;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        File fileimg = new File("sdcard/IMG_20200711_100133.jpg");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileimg.getAbsolutePath());

        Log.d("Image", fileimg.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("Image_uri", uri.toString());
        Boolean bik = fileimg.exists();
        Log.d("Image", bik.toString());
        Glide.with(this).load(uri).into(imageView);

    }
}
```

И код манифеста

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mvpphoto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить данные из локального хранилища пользователя, вам не достаточно просто прописать пермишены в Manifest. Вы должны явно запросить пермишены у пользователя:

Этот кусок кода показывает как можно обработать ответ пользователя:

```
// Register the permissions callback, which handles the user's response to the
// system permissions dialog. Save the return value, an instance of
// ActivityResultLauncher, as an instance variable.
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(new RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
            // app.
        } else {
            // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
            // features requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
            // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
            // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
            // decision.
        }
    });
```

Этот кусок кода показывает как можно запросить разрешение у пользователя:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        CONTEXT, Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // You can use the API that requires the permission.
    performAction(...);
} else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(...)) {
    // In an educational UI, explain to the user why your app requires this
    // permission for a specific feature to behave as expected. In this UI,
    // include a "cancel" or "no thanks" button that allows the user to
    // continue using your app without granting the permission.
    showInContextUI(...);
} else {
    // You can directly ask for the permission.
    // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
            Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION);
}
```

Более подробно можно прочесть в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java).

Comment: Спасибо, как раз только понял, что я никакие разрешения в самой программе не выдавал, исправил и заработало)